# Second UICollectionView not reloading

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to implement two `UICollectionView` in the same `UIViewController`. However, It's going wrong, when I run the app just one `UICollectionView` shows up, the other just keeps in blank. I've trying many ways to fix that, but I always end up failing.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewBanner: UICollectionView!


    var dataSource: [Content] = [Content]()
    var dataBanner: [Banner] = [Banner]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getBanner { (data) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dataBanner = data
                self.collectionViewBanner.reloadData()
            }
        }


        getAudiobooksAPI { (data) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dataSource = data
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.collectionView.tag == 1 {
            return  self.dataSource.count
        } else {
            return self.dataBanner.count
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

            let content = self.dataSource[indexPath.item]

            cell.bookLabel.text = content.descricao
            cell.bookImage.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")

            return cell

        } else if (collectionView == self.collectionViewBanner) {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCellBanner", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

            let content = self.dataBanner[indexPath.item]

            cell.bannerImage.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")

            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

}

extension UIImageView {
    func setImage(url : String, placeholder: String, callback : (() -> Void)? = nil){
        self.image = UIImage(named: "no-photo")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: url)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.image = image
                if let callback = callback{
                    callback()
                }                    
            })

        }).resume()
    }
}
```

The other `UICollectionView` should appear above this one. What I'm doing wrong?

App Running Image

[image]

***[EDIT]***
I'm debugging the code, and I put a breakpoint on these lines. So, what happened was that the compiler just read the "if", doesn't go into the "else".

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.collectionView.tag == 1 {
        return  self.dataSource.count
    } else {
        return self.dataBanner.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you called the delegates for two collection views

Comment: Hello@iOS ! Well, I just linked as DataSource on storyboard

Comment: Ok right, are you checked the self.dataSource.count and self.dataBanner.count. is these two are returning counts?

Comment: They're returning counts normally. You can see the image above, the other UICollectionView displays Data correctly. I don't know why the other doesn't display

Comment: I think you did mistake, collectionView.reloadData() here two times you write the same code.  replace collectionView.reloadData()  to collectionViewBanner.reloadData()

Comment: You see my answer and try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getBanner { (data) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.dataBanner = data
        self.collectionViewBanner.reloadData()
        }
    }


    getAudiobooksAPI { (data) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dataSource = data
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }


   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (collectionView == self.collectionView) { 
       return self.dataSource.count 
    }else if (collectionView == self.collectionViewBanner) { 
       return self.dataBanner.count 
    } else { 
       return nil 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I updated the question posting a little bit more information on the bottom. Could you check, please? I'll also try to implement your suggestion

Comment: I updated my answer, are you check. You need to reload two collection views. But you did only one self.collectionViewBanner.reloadData(), self.collectionView.reloadData()

Comment: I did, unfortunately the error persists. I'll update the question with your answer.

Comment: if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
    return  self.dataSource.count
    }else if (collectionView == self.collectionViewBanner) {
    return self.dataBanner.count
    } else { return nil }

Comment: Could you write as an answer for me, please? Then I can check it as SOLVED! YEAAH! :)

Comment: I updated my answer now, try again. If it's not working remove delegates in storyboard and write delegates programmatically in viewDidLoad like collectionView.delegate = self, collectionView.dataSoure = self, and collectionViewBanner.delegate = self, collectionViewBanner.dataSource = self

Answer (score 1):

Please Use My code it will solve your Problem

First change

firstchange in collectionViewBanner.reloadData

Second Change

Just check NumberofiteminSection method

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewBanner: UICollectionView!


    var dataSource: [Content] = [Content]()
    var dataBanner: [Banner] = [Banner]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getBanner { (data) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dataBanner = data
            self.collectionViewBanner.reloadData()
            }
        }


        getAudiobooksAPI { (data) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dataSource = data
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
        return  self.dataSource.count
        }else{

        return self.dataBanner.count
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        let content = self.dataSource[indexPath.item]

        cell.bookLabel.text = content.descricao
        cell.bookImage.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")

        return cell

        }else if (collectionView == self.collectionViewBanner) {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCellBanner", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

            let content = self.dataBanner[indexPath.item]

            cell.bannerImage.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")


            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

}

extension UIImageView{
    func setImage(url : String, placeholder: String, callback : (() -> Void)? = nil){
        self.image = UIImage(named: "no-photo")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: url)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            guard error == nil else{
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.image = image
                if let callback = callback{
                    callback()
                }


            })

        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there! Did you just replaced the if statement?

Comment: @Bruno Vavretchek just replace numberOfItemsInSection method in your code

Comment: I'll, but the problem was the "If", correct? Just for my knowledge

Comment: if you dont want to use if , correct alternate solution is use collectionview to tag = 1 and collectionview banner = 2 please give tag 1 and 2 and match

Answer (score 0):

You are forget to reload **collectionViewBanner**. just

```
collectionViewBanner.reloadData()
```